# With single button, how to change div background color in order listed, not randomly

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, onclick, background-color

I'm working with the code below to change the background color of the div on button click. It chooses the colors randomly (math.random), but I'd like it to choose the colors in listed order (red > blue > yellow > etc.). Can anyone help me with this?  Thanks in advance!

```
<style>
#changecolor2 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>

<script>
var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange", "black", "cyan", "magenta"]
function changeColor() {
    var col = document.getElementById("changecolor");
    col.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1)];
}
</script>

<body>
<div id="changecolor2"></div>
<button onclick="changeColor();">change color</button>
</body>
```

Comment: You can always find the current background color with a simple search loop then add one to the resulting index, if the final result is above the number of colors, just subtract the number of elements, or use the modulus operator. Does that help you at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange", "black", "cyan", "magenta"];
var colorIndex = 0;
function changeColor() {
    var col = document.getElementById("changecolor2");
    if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
        colorIndex = 0;
    }
    col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
    colorIndex++;
}
window.onload = changeColor;
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/6S46U/

Answer (score 0):

Just maintain a variable that tracks the current color index. If it gets to the last color, simply go back to the first color.

```
var current = -1;
var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange", "black", "cyan", "magenta"]
function changeColor() {

    if(current > colors.length-1){
        current = 0;
    } else {
        current++;
    }

    var col = document.getElementById("changecolor");
    col.style.backgroundColor = colors[current];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange", "black", "cyan", "magenta"]
    function changeColor() {
        if(count >= colors.length-1){
            count = 0;
        } else {
            count++;
        }

        document.getElementById("changecolor2").style.backgroundColor = colors[count];
    }
</script>
```

This will help you and will be changing the background color in cyclic manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
var count = 0;
$(".button").click(function() {
    $("body").css("background-color", colors[count]);
    count++
    count >= colors.length ? count = 0: count ;
})
```